YAJL FREE RPGLE (error Parsing data Json)
I am having problems when using the YAJL tool.
when moving data from IFS data to docnode (yajl), and I tried to debug the program, the docnode field contained DOCNODE SPP:000000080088ADC10.
while the data in the STMF is {"code":400,"errors":[{"code":400,"details":"invalid signature","message":"Bad Request"}],"message":"bad.request","responseTime":"20240424070955"}
this my complete code :
H DFTACTGRP(*NO) Option(*SrcStmt : *NoDebugIO)
H BNDDIR('HTTPAPI')
H BNDDIR('YAJL')
fgenpar1   if   e           k disk    usropn
/copy qrpglesrc,httpapi_h
/include yajl_h
D list_t          ds                  qualified
D                                     template
D   @pktnme                     15a
D   @pktcde                     16a
D   @denom                       3A
D   @valdity                     2A
D   @invblc                      1A
D result          ds                  qualified
D   xode                         3a   varying
D   success                      1n
D   errmsg                     500a   varying
D   list                              likeds(list_t) dim(999)
D docNode         s                   like(yajl_val)
D node            s                   like(yajl_val)
D list            s                   like(yajl_val)
D val             s                   like(yajl_val)
D rc              s             10I 0
D msg             s             52A
D URL             S            600A    varying
D IFS             S           5000A    varying
D i               s             10i 0
D X               s             10i 0
D lastElem        s             10i 0
D errMsg          s            500a   varying inz('')
D getparm         PR            50A
D  pkey                         10A   value
D gatesvckey      s             50a
D getpaketx       s             50a
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parameter Key
*------------------------------------------------------------------------
C     *entry        plist
C                   parm                    code              3
C                   parm                    @data           118
C                   parm                    pkt_name         14
C                   parm                    pkt_code         16
C                   parm                    denom             3
C                   parm                    valdty            2
C                   parm                    inv               1
c                   parm                    @msg              2
c                   parm                    rsptim           14
C                   parm                    rsp               3
C                   parm                    rspdsc           52

*------------------------------------------------------------------------

Main program                                                           *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Free
 exsr #init;                                                            
 exsr #getparm;                                                         
                                                                        
 callp http_debug(*off);                                                
 url= %trim(GETPAKETX)                                                  
    + 'key='+%trim(gatesvckey);                                         
 // Create ifs file                                
 ifs='/tmp/datarsp.json';                          
                                                   
 // Pust http                                      
 rc = http_url_get(URL: IFS);                      
 if rc<>1;                                         
    msg = http_error;                              
    *inlr =*on;                                    
 endif;                                            
                                                   
 docNode= yajl_stmf_load_tree ( ifs : errMsg );    
 if errMsg <> '';                                  
    // handle error                                
    rspdsc = 'Timeout!';                           
    yajl_tree_free(docNode);                       
    *inlr = *on;                                   
    return;                                            
 endif;                                                
                                                       
 node = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'xode');             
 result.xode = YAJL_get_string(node);                  
                                                       
 list = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'list');             
 i = 0;                                                
 dow YAJL_ARRAY_LOOP( list: i: node );                 
     lastElem = i;                                     
                                                       
     val  = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'paketName');    
     result.list(i).@pktnme = YAJL_get_string(val);    
                                                       
     val  = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'paketCode');    
     result.list(i).@pktcde = YAJL_get_string(val);    
                                                       
     val  = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'denom');        
     result.list(i).@denom = YAJL_get_string(val);     
     val  = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'validity');               
     result.list(i).@valdity= YAJL_get_string(val);              
                                                                 
     val  = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'inventoryBalance');       
     result.list(i).@invblc = YAJL_get_string(val);              
 enddo;                                                          
                                                                 
 node = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'success');                    
 result.success = YAJL_is_true(node);                            
 node = YAJL_object_find(docNode: 'errmsg');   
 result.errmsg= YAJL_get_string(node);         
                                               
 yajl_tree_free(docNode);                      
                                               
 *inlr=*on;                                    
 return;                                       

/End-free
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

Init Subroutine
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Free
begsr #init;
endsr;
/End-Free
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

Get Parm Transaction                                                  *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Free
begsr #getparm;

// Get key api
gatesvckey=%trim(getparm('KEYSVC'));
// Get URL api
getpaketx=%trim(getparm('GETPAKET'));
endsr;
/End-Free
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub Procedure getparm
*------------------------------------------------------------------------

P getparm         B
D getparm         PI            50A
D  pkey                         10A   value
D  pparm          s             50A
/Free
 open genpar1;                            
 chain pkey genpar1;                      
 if %found (genpar1);                     
    pparm=genkey;                         
 else;                                    
    pparm=*blanks;                        
 endif;                                   
 close genpar1;                           
                                          
 return pparm;                            
                                          
                                          

/End-free
P                 E
this capture in directory :
enter image description here
solution for my problems
